# No Printers are detected when running the site outside of Visual Studio 2013 in IIS7

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, system.drawing

I've built an application to print documents.
When running the application using Visual Studio - debugging mode I could receive the list of available printers using :

```
PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters
```

and then , I select one of them to print the document using :

```
PrintDocument printDocument = new PrintDocument();
printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Fax" ; //or any other listed printer that is returned from the method above
printDocument.PrintPage += printDocument_PrintPage;
printDocument.Print();

void printDocument_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Red,10),new Rectangle(0,0,100,100));
}
```

This works inside of Visual Studio, but when I migrate it to IIS 7 root folder **on the same computer**, it gives an error "there's no printers installed"

Note: I still can get the same list of available printers when I deploy the application to the root folder, but when Print() method is called, the web application throws the error.

I am using the namespace **System.Drawing.Printing**

Update : I did check the **System.Printing** namespace  reference page, it also shows a box says :

> "Classes within the System.Printing namespace are not
>   supported for use within a Windows service or ASP.NET application or
>   service."

Comment: Printers are a per-user account setting. I'm guessing that the application pool isn't running under your user account. Also, [System.Drawing.Printing Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing(v=vs.110).aspx): "Classes within the System.Drawing.Printing namespace are not supported for use within a Windows service or ASP.NET application or service."

Comment: since I am able to get the available printers list , I don't think it is a user account settings issue , thank you for the link

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, you could see in service how RPC (in services) is running (network service | local sytem) and put that in the application pool on IIS adance setting Identity.

I hope I could help!.